Gatling print failed users in a file
I am using Gatling for performance testing tool. I want to write the session attribute username in a file.txt when it fails or exits for an user. I am using Gatling using scala language.
Scenario :

the username is taken from the csv file and still available in the session attributes

tried experimenting

I tried using the After() hook but it will work at the end of simulation not for each user execution and still it wont print at the end as well.

-- Thanks

There're several ways how to do it. 
First: Implement logic within a scenario as a step to check for failure, then extract a value from the Session and write it to a file.
...
.exec { session =>
      if (session.isFailed) {
        val username = session("username").as[String]
        // the method which writes to file
      }
      session
    }

Second: Set-up file appender for logback. Thus, we'll essentially be logging all errors and subsequently processing them to extract all the necessary information.
In logback-test.xml add:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>file.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    
    <logger name="io.gatling.http.engine.response" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>


Then just post-process the log file with the sed or similar tools.
sed -n 's/.*username -> \([^,]*\).*/\1/p' file.log


I am not sure about the first step But I am already have the simulation-error log with the transaction failures which holds the session variables. Then I will run a shell script at the end which will extract the usernames.
